# Using the dot and return statement in cypher queries

Tags: apache-age

Why does this query return `Yes!`

```
SELECT *
FROM cypher('graph_name', $$
    MATCH (`This isn\'t a common variable`)
    WHERE `This isn\'t a common variable`.name = 'A'
    RETURN `This isn\'t a common variable`.happy
$$) as (happy agtype);
```

```
| happy   |
——————————-
| "Yes!"  |
——————————-
| (1 row) |
```

Exactly from the docs [here](https://age.apache.org/age-manual/master/clauses/return.html)

Answer (score 1):

The query searched for nodes that has a `name` property that equals `A` and returns the value of the `happy` property of the matched notes.

If you look at the `Return all elements` example right above, you can see that this node exists :

```
{"id": 281474976710659, "label": "", 
"properties": {"age": 55, "name": "A", "happy": "Yes!"}}::vertex
```

and this is the node that matches with the above query. As you can see the `happy` property of this node has the value `Yes!`.

Answer (score 1):

To use a variable name that starts with a number or includes spaces or non-alphanumeric characters, you should enclose the name in backticks " ` ". Here's an example:

```
SELECT * from cypher('test', $$
    WITH 25
    AS `hello world`
    RETURN `hello world` 
$$) as (result agtype);

 result 
--------
 25
(1 row)
```

In your query, `This isn\'t a common variable` is used as a variable name and is enclosed in backticks. If we replace it with another variable name, say 'n', the query would be easier to understand:

```
SELECT *
FROM cypher('graph_name', $$
    MATCH (n)
    WHERE n.name = 'A'
    RETURN n.happy
$$) as (happy agtype);
```

This query simply returns the 'happy' property of all the node where the 'name' property is equal to 'A'.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the [Docs](https://age.apache.org/age-manual/master/clauses/return.html#variable-with-uncommon-characters),
"*To introduce a placeholder that is made up of characters that are not contained in the English alphabet, you can use the ` to enclose the variable...*".

This means if the placeholder has a symbol in it, it has to be within backticks. The conventional way is like so `MATCH (n)`, where `(n)` is the placeholder.
For something different like the example in the docs which is **MATCH (`This isn't a common variable`)**, it has to be enclosed hence it will result in a syntax error.

The query returns **'Yes'** because it prints out the value of the property `happy`. Check the output in the previous example in the docs for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Every language has its own syntax. In most of the cases, the space or numbers in the variable names are not allowed in most of the languages but in the case of Apache Age, its allowed but it has a little different way of calling and using it.

For example, if you have any character in the name which is not an alphabet, then you have to use this sign (`) to enclose that name. Same is being done in this query which has created a little confusion.

Normally, we write query in this way in Apache Age.

```
select * from cypher('graph_name',$$
Match (n{name:'A'})
Return n.name 
$$) as (name agtype);
```

This query will return the name of the n vertex which has name='A'

Now,coming to our questioned query, everything is just same but the confusion is with the naming style.

```
SELECT *
FROM cypher('graph_name', $$
MATCH (`This isn\'t a common variable`)
WHERE `This isn\'t a common variable`.name = 'A'
RETURN `This isn\'t a common variable`.happy
$$) as (happy agtype);
```

What this query is doing is taking a vertex named (This isn't a common variable) as then checking if it's name attribute is 'A' , then it will return the happy attribute of that (This isn't a common variable) vertex.

The result can vary from 0 to n rows because if there can multiple vertex with this name and if there are multiple vertexes having name:A then it will return the happy property of all that nodes.

In our case, it has only one vertex with that name:A, so it has returned one row only and the happy attribute was yes, so it has put yes in the answer.